# Do some process to part of dataframe in python

Tags: python

My dataframe df has both numeric and non numeric columns

I want to fill Nulls with Mean in the numeric columns only

I can do this

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']

df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=numerics)

df.fillna(df.mean())
```

but i will be losing the non numeric fields

I want to fill NA with mean at the same time not to loose the categorical columns

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried the last line only? `df.mean()` will return the means of columns which it _can_ calculate, and thus `df.fillna` will know which columns to fill with what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can store the numeric data using

```py
df.select_dtypes(exclude=numerics).fillna(df.mean())
```

Then combine the non-numeric data with numeric data